If $P(\cos t,\sin t, t) = \sum_{i=0}^n Q_i(\cos t, \sin t) t^i = 0$, then $Q_i(\cos t, \sin t)\equiv 0$. Can we say the same for $\cosh t,\sinh t$?

Claim: Let $P\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$ be a polynomial. Write $P$ as $P=\sum_{i=0}^n Q_i Z^i$, with $Q_i \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. If $P(\cos t, \sin t, t)\equiv 0$, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $Q_i(\cos t,\sin t)\equiv 0$, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
Proof. Fix $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $p(Z):=P(\cos t_0,\sin t_0, Z)$. This one-variable polynomial $p$ has infinitely many roots, namely $t_0+2k\pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. In fact, from our hypothesis and periodicity of trigonometric functions, we have \begin{align*} 0&= P(\cos(t_0+2k\pi),\sin(t_0+2k\pi),t_0+2k\pi)\\ &= P(\cos t_0,\sin t_0,t_0+2k\pi)\\ &= p(t_0+2k\pi). \end{align*} Therefore, $p$ must be identically zero. Hence, we have $Q_i(\cos t_0,\sin t_0)=0$, for every $i=1,\ldots,n$. Now, $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed but arbitrary. The claim follows.

My question: Can we say the same using $\cosh t$, $\sinh t$ instead of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$? We can't rely on the periodicity property in this case.

By considering $P$ and $Q$ as polynomials with complex coefficients, an analogous proof works, by using that  $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ are $2\pi i$-periodic.

Let $m$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
m=\max\{\deg Q_i\,:\, i\in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}\}.
\end{align*}
For each $i$, there is some polynomial $\tilde{Q}_i \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that
\begin{align*}
e^{mt}Q_i(\cosh t,\sinh t)&= e^{mt}Q_i\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2},\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\right)\\
&= \tilde{Q}_i(e^t).
\end{align*}
Setting $M=\max \{\deg \tilde{Q}_i\}$, we can write $\tilde{Q}_i = \sum_{j=0}^{M}q_{i,j}X^j$, for certain constants $q_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}$.
Using the hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
0&=e^{mt}P(\cosh t, \sinh t,t) \\
&=e^{mt}\sum_{i=0}^nQ_i(\cosh t, \sinh t) t^i\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \tilde{Q}_i (e^t) t^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{M} q_{i,j}e^{jt} t^i\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^M \left(\sum_{i=0}^n q_{i,j}t^i\right) (e^{t})^j
\end{align*}
Now, since the function $e^t$ is not an algebraic function, the polynomials given by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^n q_{i,j}t^i
\end{align*}
must be all identically zero.
Hence $\tilde{Q}_i$ is identically zero (not only applied on $e^t$ but as polynomial!).
But then,
\begin{align*}
Q_i(\cosh t, \sinh t) &= e^{-mt} \tilde{Q}_i(e^t) = e^{-mt}\cdot 0 \equiv 0,
\end{align*}
for every $i\in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
Edit: To see how $Q$ may be nonzero even though $\tilde{Q}$ is identically zero, just take $$Q(X,Y)=X^2-Y^2-1.$$
$Q$ is nonzero and satisfies $Q(\cosh t, \sinh t)= 0$, $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
\tilde{Q}(e^t)&= e^{2t} Q(\cosh t, \sinh t)\\
&= e^{2t}\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\right)^2-e^{2t}\left(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\right)^2-e^{2t}\\
&= \left(\frac{e^{2t}+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2}\right)^2-e^{2t}\\
&= \left(\frac{e^{2t}+1}{2}+\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{e^{2t}+1}{2}-\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2}\right)-e^{2t}\\
&= e^{2t}-e^{2t}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\tilde{Q}(X)\equiv 0$.
